# Multiple objectives regression with bounded output in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, openai-gym

Im trying to use Keras to solve the following OpenAi gym [environment](https://gym.openai.com/envs/Humanoid-v1).
It uses `~360 neurons` for input and then it uses `17 real number outputs` with the `range [-0.4, 0.4]`. All the examples I have found online uses much simpler output layers with a single objective and no bounds.

My questions are:

1. Do I need any special functions since the outputs are bounded?
2. Are there any example on how to constuct such a output layer with Keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use mean squared error for such a task.

However you can define your own metric to be optimized against. An example definition can be found here:: (https://github.com/EdwardTyantov/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation/blob/master/metric.py).

Comment: That would not handle the bounds?

Comment: oh you want an output function that only outputs between -0.4 and 0.4?

Comment: You can do a sigmoid and append a 1x1 convolution that uses 0.8 as weight and -0.4 as bias and is not trainable. Than your classifier abouts those specific values. However if you use linear output and mean squared error you get outputs of this range anyways and if you really do not want any values that are higher you can just clamp them afterwards.